# How to enable denoising for my final render?

Tags: rendering, external-applications, denoise, luxrender-render-engine

I have been fiddling around with the *LuxCoreRender* rendering settings, but both *denoisers* do not seem to be having effect on my frames that I have rendered.

I have re-installed *LuxCoreRender* multiple times, and used the default settings + my own custom settings to try to get it to work, but for some reason it will not. The viewport denoiser is working perfectly, however. Also, if I set the denoiser settings to be heavier on denoising, Blender will quit, running out of memory.

**Q:** Is there some way I can use the same settings for the viewport rendered view, and somehow apply them to the rendered frame settings?

Comment: When viewing the render make sure the dropdown on the top right of the *Image Viewer* is set to the correct pass. You can also render to exr multilayer to get both passes (denoised and beauty) in one file for comp.

Comment: Nope, was a comment to this question (before you changed title and the whole content https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/159746/revisions) I'd suggest ask a new one.

Comment: Does it save the rendering as the image editor view type then? Because I rendered a luxcore animation, and it was not denoised.

Comment: Your settings worked by the way, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the dropdown on the top right of the *Image Viewer* is set to the correct pass (`DENOISED`):

[image]

I'd suggest render to `OpenEXR Multilayer` to get both passes (beauty and denoised) in one file for comp:

[image]

**Alternatively** you can add a *Render Layer* node in the *Compositor* to get the `DENOISED` socket and connect both passes to a *File Output* node or even blend between both passes before saving:

[image]

Note: The *Composite Node* has only one input socket so this approach does not store any *raw data*.